# Tables side by side with two captions for each one

Tags: tables

In fact, I have tried to put these tables side by side, I have already checked some methods in tex.stackexchange but they display two table with one caption. I want both table each one with its appropriate caption here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\usepackage[thin, , thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]

\centering
\caption{The parameters 1}
\begin{tabular}{ c c } 
\toprule
\makecell{ parameters}  &  value \\   
\midrule
Rated value &  3.5\\
time & 50 s     \\
value 1 & 100    \\
value 2 & 200  \\
value 3 & 300  \\
value 4 & 400 \\
value 5 & 500  \\
value 6 & 600 \\
VALUE 7 & 700 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}
\label{tab:The parameters}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{The parameters 2}
\begin{tabular}{ c c } 
\toprule
\makecell{ parameters 2}  &  Value \\   
\midrule
time  &  0.2 s\\
value 8 & 800     \\
value 9 & 900    \\
value 10 & 1000  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}
\label{tab:The parameters 2 }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact I want both tables with their own captions

Comment: My bad!! I am sorry. Could you upload a MWE which is compilable --> this only throws errors when I try to compile.

Comment: It's okay now you can check the new code

Comment: your code is not minimal. also you not say, how you imagine to be vertical aligned both tables ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps. This is done using `minipage` environment`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\usepackage[thin, , thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\begin{document}\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering

    \caption{First Table}
    \label{tab:first_table}

    \medskip

\begin{tabular}{ c c } 
\toprule
\makecell{ parameters}  &  value \\   
\midrule
Rated value &  1.5MW\\
time & 50 s     \\
value 1 & 100    \\
value 2 & 200  \\
value 3 & 300  \\
value 4 & 400 \\
value 5 & 500  \\
value 6 & 600 \\
VALUE 7 & 700 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering

    \caption{Second Table}
    \label{tab:second_table}

    \medskip

\begin{tabular}{ c c } 
    \toprule
    \makecell{ parameters 2}  &  Value \\   
    \midrule
    time  &  0.2 s\\
    value 8 & 800     \\
    value 9 & 900    \\
    value 10 & 1000  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

with use of two `minipage` environments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}\centering
\caption{The parameters 1}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
parameters  &  value \\
\midrule
Rated value &  1.5MW\\
time & 50 s     \\
value 1 & 100    \\
value 2 & 200  \\
value 3 & 300  \\
value 4 & 400 \\
value 5 & 500  \\
value 6 & 600 \\
VALUE 7 & 700 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}\centering
\caption{The parameters 2}
\label{tab:The parameters 2 }
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
parameters 2    &  Value \\
\midrule
time            &  0.2 s\\
value 8         & 800     \\
value 9         & 900    \\
value 10        & 1000  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

*note:* from your mwe i remove all in my solution not used packages.

Comment: Can we have a global caption for both tables at bottom

Comment: @alper, why not? Global settings are preferred, since it garant uniform caption styles. All depends what you wish and how you like that appears both tables. If you have some problem with this, please ask new question (with MWE which reproduce your problem).